# Benifits of schema 1.1

Tags: xml, xsd

Is there any significant benefit of using schema 1.1 over 1.0?

Comment: You could just google it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29#Version_1.1

Comment: Yes there are quite a few interesting improvements but its significance depends on your requirements.

Comment: My company requires me to learn schematron. I am just curious if XML schema 1.1 do everything thing that schematron do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/